# Powering 800mA router for approximately 1 min

Tags: power, capacitor, failure

I need a cheap way of powering my internet modem (rated at 0.8A, 12V) for approximately 1 minute in case of power failure (which happens every hour or two) till my secondary power takes over.

I am thinking capacitors but i am not sure if they will be able to power for 1 minute.

Edit: If i connect a 12 v battery in parallel and update the power adopter to 14V to charge the battery, would this kind of setup damage my modem?

Comment: A battery in parallel works, but only with a battery charger that prevents overcharging, not a normal power supply. If your modem is ok with 14V should be listed in the datasheet.

Comment: **Why does it take a *minute* before your secondary power source takes over?** Even a cheap UPS has a fail-over time measured in the low two-digit *milliseconds* and will be able to run such a load for several hours (0.8A × 12V = 9.6W; 7 Ah × 12V = 84 Wh; 84 Wh ÷ 9.6W = 8.75 h). A generator takes somewhat longer but a consumer backup generator still shouldn't need anywhere near a minute to stabilize the output voltage and frequency (this is why when running critical equipment on a generator you need a battery backup as well to cover for the time until the generator's output has stabilized).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling i have a generator as a backup which starts approximately 30 seconds after power failure and takes another 10-30 seconds to stabilize.

Comment: @haxan7 I see. In that case I'd definitely suggest going with PeterJ's suggestion of a small battery-based UPS to supplement the generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attached an old (probably expired) 12v car battery with the modem in parallel, and it works perfectly, i am able to run the modem on battery power for hours, and it didn't even cost me a penny but i may need to periodically charge the batteries.

Answer (score 13):

One problem with capacitors for power backup applications is not so much if they can be used, it's also a matter of cost. Just using an [on-line supercap discharge calculator](http://www.circuits.dk/calculator_capacitor_discharge.htm) as an example and plugging in a few numbers assuming a 12 -> 9V drop would still keep it running OK I came up with a 20F capacitor for a bit over a minute.

Although a bit larger than required on Digikey at the moment the cheapest part that I found that met or exceeded those requirements was a [58F 16V Capacitor](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/BMOD0058%20E016%20B02/1182-1027-ND/3079291) at a bit over $US140. That's not too over the top but if you were trying to connect across a normal modem power supply you'd also need to consider the inrush current as the capacitor charges so it might not be as simple as just placing one across the supply.

I'd expect that for that voltage / current assuming that the modem is normally powered from mains that a small UPS using an SLA battery would be a cheaper and better solution. While SLA batteries do degrade over time I'd expect a small UPS to be able to provide that small amount of backup time for quite a long period, maybe say five years until the batteries needed replacing.

As an addendum to your updated question when connecting an SLA battery in parallel you may experience similar problems with an inrush current. While I wouldn't expect the battery to draw much current after a few minutes of discharge (if fully charged at the start) for safety you should also consider what would happen if power was out for hours and the battery discharged completely.

Comment: I wasn't aware that capacitors would cost this much. If i am to buy a battery, shouldn't i upgrade the power adopter to 14 V so that it charges the battery this way i wouldn't need a ups.

Comment: @haxan7, they're not the magic bullet a lot of people expect at least at the moment for power applications. Some capacitors do cost less than a cent in volume, but you're normally talking in uF or less in that case so millions of times smaller in capacitance.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here.

1) Use a UPS supply that is ready to go. This will cost a couple hundred dollars.

2) You can create a custom board which can detect 12V primary failure and generate 12V. You can use one Lithium Ion/Poly battery along with a DC/DC converter to raise the 3.7V nominal to 12V.

Taking into account that you're multiplying the input voltage by 3.25 you will need an input current of 2594mA. This is the ideal situation. In reality, taking into account DC/DC inefficiency, lets say 20%, so you'll actually need a battery which can sustain 3200mA. Several batteries such as 10Ah batteries can support this for one minute. Of course this method is a bit more complicated, and a UPS might be the easy way.

For battery charging, TI provides several devices that can support charging the battery.